# Removing duplicate foreign key rows in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a table `Stores`, and a table `Schools`.  This is a one to many relationship-- multiple schools can be served by the same store, but not vice-versa.

Earlier on in development, I made the mistake of repeating the same store multiple times in the `Stores` database.  I inserted rows like:

```
Store_ID| Store_URL
1       | http://sameurl.com
2       | http://sameurl.com
```

And then if two different schools were at that same store, I'd be referencing `1` in one school row, and `2` in another.

I'm able to identify duplicates quite easily by using `GROUP BY` on `Store_URL` and using `COUNT()` to identify duplicates.

The difficult task ahead of me is making all the `Schools` point to non-duplicate `Stores`.  If I simply delete duplicate `Stores`, I'll have `Schools` which point to nonexistent rows.

What can I do to eliminate duplicates and make schools that share the same store point to the same `Store` row?

Note: there are thousands of schools and stores.  Manual solutions don't work.

Comment: I am currently working on a query to go along with my text suggestion

Comment: For the delete part, can you delete any store with no school, or only the duplicate store records?

Comment: I don't expect there to be any stores without schools, though I do expect the opposite to occur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `School` table has a `store_ID` from what you've said.

I would start by figuring out for each duplicate, which `store_ID` you want to keep.  I will also assume that you want it to be the lowest ID value.  I would then update the `School`s' `store_ID` to be the `MIN(store_ID)` for the current URL they have.  You should then be free to delete the extra `store_ID` records

This is how I would go about the update:

```
UPDATE sch
SET sch.Store_ID = matcher.store_ID
FROM Schools AS sch
INNER JOIN Stores AS st ON sch.store_ID = st.store_ID
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MIN(st.store_id) AS store_ID, store_url
   FROM Schools AS sch
   INNER JOIN Stores AS st ON sch.store_ID = st.store_ID
   GROUP BY Store_URL
) AS matcher ON st.Store_URL = matcher.Store_Url
   AND st.Store_ID != matcher.store_ID
```

If you are able to delete stores that do not have an associated school, the following query will remove the extra rows:

```
DELETE FROM st
FROM Stores AS st
LEFT JOIN Schools AS sch ON st.Store_ID = sch.Store_Id
WHERE sch.Store_id IS NULL
```

If you only want to delete the Store's duplicate records, I would look at this query instead of the above:

```
DELETE FROM st
FROM Stores AS st
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MIN(st.store_ID) store_Id, st.Store_Url
   FROM Stores AS st
   GROUP BY st.Store_URL
) AS useful ON st.Store_Url = useful.Store_URL
WHERE st.Store_ID != useful.store_Id
```

Comment: Going to have to see how this works but the basic approach is what I'm going to do.  Thank you

Comment: No problem, I added a delete query that should only remove the records that were duplicates for you.

Comment: Is repeating the line `INNER JOIN Stores AS st ON sch.store_ID = st.store_ID` in your first query a typo? Also, what is the purpose of `AND st.Store_ID != match.store_ID`

Answer (score 0):

The following update statement will change the values in one school's database:

```
UPDATE Schools SET store_id = 1 WHERE store_id = 2;
DELETE FROM Stores WHERE Store_ID = 2;
```

Comment: I need to do this for thousands of schools.  It cannot be done manually like this

Comment: hundreds.  looking for a solution, like Adam Wenger's that can do it in 1 query